# Bitcoin wallet corrupted after recovered from broken HDD

Tags: wallet

I have recently managed to recover my walled.dat file from one of my old HDD that got broken in 2012(Nov/Dec) using a disk recovery program "Recover my files v4". The problem is that every bitcoin client give me "Corrupted wallet, salvage failed" error . 
There is any chance that the program i used to recover my wallet to alter/edit the wallet file or i simply need to use a 2012 version of the bitcoin client ?

Comment: There has been cases of successful recovery using older Bitcoin software.